# 2 radio button group do not work in MAUI using community toolkit MVVM

Tags: mvvm, radio-button, maui, radio-group, .net-maui

I am using .NET MAUI and I come across an issue where I have 2 different radio group, each has a selection using a binding to a bool variable. I am leveraging the NET community toolkit MVVM to do the binding. The issue is when I have those 2 groups displayed, the selected value appears on only one of them and not both. i tested whether the binding works for each, and it does (by removing one radio group at a time). I am confused, and I do understand where the issue is. Here is my code

Code for the mainPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="ok"/>
            <StackLayout >
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" WidthRequest="200" >
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0"  Content="Yes"    IsChecked="{Binding VariableA}"/>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="No"  />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout >

            <StackLayout >
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" WidthRequest="200" >
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Yes"  IsChecked="{Binding VariableB}"/>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="No"  />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

code behind for the mainpage

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    

    public MainPage(Class1 viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    
}
```

code for the view model

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class Class1 : ObservableObject
    {
        
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool variableA= true;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool variableB= true;
    }
}
```

and finally MauiProgram.cs

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Class1>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

here is the result when I run the 2 radiogroup as coded above. Can you help  me in understanding what I do wrong ?

[As you see only one radio group shows the value selected when i run the app][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXP1.png

Answer (score 2):

To add Radiobuttons to the same group you need to provide a group name to the parent-most radio group

The [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton#explicit-grouping-with-the-radiobuttongroupgroupname-attached-property) says:

The RadioButtonGroup class defines a GroupName attached property, of type string, which can be set on a `Layout<View>` object. This enables any layout to be turned into a radio button group:

XAML

```
<StackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="colors">
    <Label Text="What's your favourite colour?" />
    <RadioButton Content="Red" />
    <RadioButton Content="Green" />
    <RadioButton Content="Blue" />
    <RadioButton Content="Other" />
</StackLayout>
```

In this example, each RadioButton in the StackLayout will have its GroupName property set to colours, and will be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yellow than you for your answer. I don’t want these 2 radio groups to be the same. I want them to be different. I positioned the radiobutton.groupname at the parent stack layout and gave each a different name and the issue still remains.

Comment: If you don't want them in the same radio group why are u using grouping at all

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are designed to allow one selection out of many possible choices, and therefore when binding them, you should bind radio buttons in the same group to different variables, e.g.

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding AChecked}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding BChecked}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CChecked}"/>
```

To have multiple groups of radio buttons, you provide a group name, but you still need to bind them to different variables:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding AChecked}" GroupName="set1"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding BChecked}" GroupName="set1"/>
...
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CChecked}" GroupName="set2"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding DChecked}" GroupName="set2"/>
```

Now, only one of A or B can be checked, but at the same time either C or D can be checked.

You can get away with only binding one if you only have two options, as is your case.

Note you could also bind these to a list of items in the view model, if each had a `IsSelected` property for example.

This should "just work" without group names if the radios are in their own parent container, which is your case. Using your sample on .NET7 on Android "just works" for me:

```
<StackLayout >
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" WidthRequest="200" >
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="0"  Content="Yes"    IsChecked="{Binding VariableA}"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="No"  />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout >

<StackLayout >
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" WidthRequest="200" >
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Yes"  IsChecked="{Binding VariableB}"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="No"  />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>

<Label Text="{Binding VariableA, StringFormat='A: {0}'}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<Label Text="{Binding VariableB, StringFormat='B: {0}'}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

[image: Radio button example]

If all radio buttons had to be in the same parent container, then you could add group names accordingly.